# Props are changing in value (they should be read-only)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my code:

```
function Headline(props) {
  
  props.text = "I have changed.";
  
  return (
    <h1>{props.text}</h1>
  );
}

let title = <Headline text="Do Not Change" />;


let app = document.getElementById("app");
ReactDOM.createRoot(app).render(title);
```

The documentation on React website seems to imply that Props are read only (https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only). Why was I able to change its value then, because the final output for me was "I have changed.".

Keeping the above code on a single page does not create any errors. However, here are the steps I took to recreate it.

1. Execute `npx create-react-app anything`.

Have the following files in the `src` directory once installation is over:

The `index.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import Headline from './Headline';
import './index.css';

let title = <Headline text="Do Not Change" />;

let app = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.createRoot(app).render(title);
```

and `Headline.js` file:

```
function Headline(props) {

    props.text = "I have changed.";

    return (
        <h1>{props.text}</h1>
    );
    
}

export default Headline;
```

Now, I get the following error:

[image]

Is there any reason why I got the mutation error in the second case but the not first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer because it's javascript, you can mutate object properties if they are defined with `writable` rule (see `Object.defineProperty()`)

In react they called as read-only because props must only pass values from parent to child components, nothing else

Comment: Thanks Mike. Could you please look at some additional information to help me figure out why I get an error in second case?

Comment: In second case I think dev server created by create-react-app defines props with writable: false or Object.freeze() and add 'use strict';

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you link to says **don't do that** not **it is impossible to do that**.

The changed value renders because you change it before the first render. If it had rendered and then you, later on, changed it (e.g. from a click callback) then that wouldn't trigger a re-render.

Comment: Thanks Quentin. A tutorial I am following got errors while changing properties this way. Was it because they were using `create-react-app` from `npm`?

Comment: I have no idea what the difference between this code and the code in the tutorial you are following is, nor do I know what errors they got.

Comment: Sorry, that was a stupid question from my end. :D I will replicate all their steps and then see if I get the same error.

Comment: Hers example of what hes saying: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-nasty-data-update-z9slr?file=/src/Child.js

Comment: Quentin and @CptSosen I have added some more information after replicating steps from the tutorial. I am getting the error now. Is it possible to get an explanation based on the provided information?